# Replacing value in data frame column

Tags: r

I have a data frame df in which the monthdiff column has 0 or negative values. I would like to replace those values by 1. Unfortunately, the code below does not work

```
df$MonthDiff <- (ceiling((df$exp-df$dj)/30))
if((df$MonthDiff==0) || (df$MonthDiff<0))
 {df$MonthDiff<- 1 }
```

Alternative code variant

```
df$MonthDiff <- as.integer((ceiling((df$exp-df$dj)/30)))
    if((df$MonthDiff==0) || (df$MonthDiff<0))
     {df$MonthDiff<- 1 }
```

Comment: Don't use `||` use `|`.  Read the documentation to see why

Comment: df$monthDiff <- ifelse(df$monthDiff < 1, 1, monthDiff)

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon is a bit off.  df[df$MonthDiff < 0, "MothDiff"] <- 1

Comment: df$MonthDiff[df$MonthDiff<=0] <- 1